# Laravel eloquent multiple belongsTo seeding

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-seeding

I have three models, `User`, `Category` and `Article`.

`Article` belongs to both a `User` and a `Category` where the foreign keys `user_id` and `category_id` are `not null`.

Am lost trying to seed the database with fake data via factories accordingly, here's the seeding code...

```php
// 2 categories and 12 articles, 6 per category
// TODO: A user should have 6 articles with mixed categories 
// 3 from each category
// So we will have 2 users
factory(Category::class, 2)->create()->each(function($category) {
    factory(User::class)->create()->each(function($user) use ($category) {
        // How to assign an Article to $category or $user while creating?
        $user->articles()->createMany(
                    factory(Article::class, 3)->make()->toArray()
                ); // category_id can't be null
        // OR
        $category->articles()->createMany(
                    factory(Article::class, 3)->make()->toArray()
                ); // user_id can't be null
    });
});
```

I'll get one of two errors, either

> Column user_id doesn't have a default value

Or

> Column category_id doesn't have a default value

Which is logical due to the `Article` table migration

```php
$table->increments('id');
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
```

How can I pass the `category_id` or `user_id` to the factory call?
Is there a better way to acheive this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add them like so? `factory(Article::class, 3)->make(['category_id' => $category->id])->toArray()` Does that work?

Comment: @kerbholz yes, thank you, make it an answer and I'll upvote and accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override attributes for your factory by passing an array with the desired attributes to the `make()` method:

Change

```
$user->articles()->createMany(
  factory(Article::class, 3)->make()->toArray()
);
```

to

```
$user->articles()->createMany(
  factory(Article::class, 3)->make([
    'category_id' => $category->id
  ])->toArray()
);
```

to override the `category_id` attribute.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database-testing#using-factories

Answer (score 0):

Seed the categories separately.

Then seed the users and inside it seed the articles.
In the article factory file `ArticleFactory`:

```php
$factory->define(App\Article::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    return [
        'category_id' => App\Category::inRandomOrder()->value('id'),
        ....
        'created_at' => time(),
        'updated_at' => time(),
    ];
});
```

Comment: `inRandomOrder` won't achieve the requirement of 6 articles per category

Comment: @CaddyDZ then change it to `withCount('articles')->orderBy('articles_count', 'asc')`

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

### First

make users create when you make a new article from factory

```
$factory->define(App\Article::class, function ($faker) use ($factory)  {
    return [
        'user_id' => $factory->create(App\User::class)->id,
        'title' => $faker->sentence,
        'body' => $faker->paragraph
    ];
});
```

### Second

from your seeder
in this example i will make **3 categories * 6 Articles**

```
factory('App\Category', 3)->create()->each(function($u) {
    $u->posts()->save(factory('App\Article', 6)->create());
});
```

Comment: `$factory->create(App\User::class)->id` will whip up a new user for each article, doesn't satisfy the requirement of `A user should have 6 articles`, this way a user would only have 1 article

Comment: No the first part just for create user foreach article in factory but in your seeder you will make 3 category each of them has 6 article